# gnuplot: superimposing contour plot and data on x-y plane

Tags: plot, gnuplot, contour

I am new to gnuplot. I am trying to superimpose both a contour plot and some data points on the x-y plane.

Data for my contour is given (`surface1.txt`) [here](http://pastebin.com/AAvhq9vR)
Data for the single points is given (`points1.txt`) [here](http://pastebin.com/0Ws7BxCR)

I am trying to run this script:

```
set multiplot
# plot the contour from the surface1.txt
unset key
set dgrid3d
unset surface
set contour base
# these values need to be set (requirement)
set cntrparam level incremental 0.16, 0.259, 4.47
set view 0,0
unset ztics
splot "surface1.txt" with lines
# plot the points on the x-y plane
unset xtics
unset ytics
splot "points1.txt"
unset multiplot
```

and I am getting this output:

[image]

As you can see, the single points that I am trying to put on the x-y plane also comes as contour, what I need to do is:

1. display the points from "points1.txt" as single points (not contour)
2. the plot is zoomed out, I need a full screen image.
3. move the y-axis ticks from right to left vertical.
4. remove all the colors. I need a grayscale image.

Please help.

**EDIT:**
I have also tried this way --

```
set contour base
set cntrparam bspline
set cntrparam level incremental 0.16, 0.259, 4.47
set view map
set dgrid3d
unset key
splot 'surface1.txt' nosurface with lines, \
    'points1.txt' nocontour
```

and I am getting this plot --

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things you must regard:

1. `set dgrid3d` interpolates your data and is thought to be used for non-gridded data. There is no option `nodgrid3d` which allows you to use it only for one plot part. This is what you see in your second attempt: the data for the points is interpolated and a 10x10 grid is generated.

   However, you don't need to use this, because you have gridded data, but are missing a few empty lines in your data file. Just insert a single empty line when the x-value changes, like:

   ```
   ...
   0.0 0.7999999999999999  2.0477812692428836
   0.0 0.8999999999999999  2.3096674656635523
   0.0 0.9999999999999999  2.5772908911794614

   0.1 0.0 0.8254201558219569
   0.1 0.1 1.0350909705482707
   0.1 0.2 1.2504990143698247
   ...
   ```
2. Use the `nosurface` option for the contours, and `nocontours` when plotting the points.

A possible script could be:

```
set contour base
set cntrparam level incremental 0.16, 0.259, 4.47
unset key
set view map
set for [i=1:20] linetype i lc rgb 'black'

set terminal pngcairo dashed size 600,400
set output 'contour-with-points.png'
splot 'surface1.txt' with lines nosurface, 'points1.txt' with points nocontour pt 7
```

with the result[image]

I used the `pngcairo` terminal only for this example, for your document you should probably use a vector format, like produced by pdfcairo, postscript, epslatex or similar.

Comment: this works!, thanks. But is there any other way around for `set for [i=1:20] linetype i lc rgb 'black'` ? as I am not sure there will be exactly 20 lines or not.

Comment: You can use `set linetype 1 lc rgb 'black'; set linetype cycle 1` with version 4.6.5.